# Are there internet users connecting with HTTP/1.0?

Tags: http, users, blocking

**Are there internet users connecting with HTTP/1.0?** Such as over a proxy. Because I'm going to block HTTP/1.0 since most of the bots are using HTTP/1.0.

Comment: If you would like specifics on what to do, please add your platform (e.g. linux/apache, or windows/IIS, including version numbers, etc.)

Comment: FreeBSD 6.3-PRERELEASE,
Apache 2.0.61,
PHP 5.2.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is mostly in use by bots and other crawlers, why not block bots the regular way, by adding/changing the robots.txt file (for the "law-obeying" bots) or by changing your .htaccess file to block the criminals. [This site](http://www.clockwatchers.com/robots_bad.html) is one of many describing these procedures.

**Update**: If I were to write a malicious bot today, I'd use http/1.1, just to throw off people blocking 1.0 :).

Second, there may be some legacy browsers that may still use 1.0 (AFAIK all recent browsers use 1.1). These may also include accessibility-type browsers (like Lynx, or blind-support browsers) or browsers on phones/devices that cannot be updated (i.e. my Nokia 6310's browser uses 1.0 - luckily I've switched to a Blackberry). Blocking 1.0 might lose you that type of traffic.

But here's the real easy solution: monitor your logs for a while. If you don't see a lot of 1.0 requests - block it, safely assuming you won't lose too much traffic.

Comment: most of them are using web browsers' user-agent strings. i'm trying to block only the criminal ones. and i have already blocked .ru mail addresses and chinase ip addresses. but the question is about http/1.0 users. I don't care about bots, criminals or not. I might block all of them, except Googlebot.

Comment: Check if my update addresses your comment.

Comment: lynx, links, curl and wget are using HTTP/1.1 by default. May be very old versions are using HTTP/1.0. I do not expect a decent crawler to use HTTP/1.0, because HTTP/1.1 is required for name based virtual hosts.

Comment: I've had a blind colleague who's been using a reader (essentially a box connected to a machine that reads the characters on the screen out loud). It uses a proprietary browser. He has used it since 1994 (it actually uses a pre-USB serial connector) and I very much doubt its browser uses 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Squid uses HTTP/1.0