# Is HTTP 1.0 being used nowadays?

Tags: proxy, http

Its a stupid question to ask. Is HTTP 1.0 still used by any client or server? its because I am working on a proxy server program that requires HTTP 1.1

Comment: Huh, usually it's the other way around. The proxy can't handle 1.1, which breaks stuff. I'm interested to see what 1.1-only breaks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a [**discussion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073392/is-http-1-0-still-in-use) about this over on stackoverflow not too long ago and some [**here**](https://serverfault.com/questions/110932/are-there-internet-users-connecting-with-http-1-0) too.

The gist is that it's still in use.

Comment: And of courese you can go the site http://web-sniffer.net/ for generating and studiying various HTTP (1.1/1.0) Requests and Responses

Answer (score 4):

Yes - numerous reverse proxy packages are 1.0 only.  They will receive 1.1 requests, but all backend traffic is sent as 1.0.  [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes.
Long answer: You can't say that HTTP 1.0 is extinct. Basically there are a lot of tools that are coded using 1.0 so if you are working on a proxy you have to support both 1.0 and 1.1. [This document](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html) has some key differences between 1.0 and 1.1, it's important for you to see how 1.0 dealt with cache, and how 1.1 does.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm messing around with sockets and ports or CURL etc in PHP, I sometimes request HTTP 1.0 from the remote server so that I can guarantee the response *isn't* chunked.

Not a great reason to still use it obviously!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, especially in scripted web client solutions.